# Nested Looping inside a groovy xml builder

Tags: loops, groovy

i am trying to create an XML file using groovy script. There is a requirement to loop two things, so that the resulting XML includes all the objects as passed by the user.

Here is the code so far, with the first loop:

```
import groovy.xml.*

//map to loop
def workflows = [[ name: "A", file: "fileA" , objectName: "wf_A" , objectType: "workflow", sourceRepository: "DEV2"],
[ name: 'B' , file: 'fileB' , objectName: 'wf_B' , objectType: 'workflow', sourceRepository: 'DEV2']]

// def folderNameMap = [[ srcFolder: ["srcFolder1", "srcFolder2"], TgtFolder: ["TgtFolder1", "TgtFolder2"]],
// [srcFolder: ["srcFolder3"], TgtFolder: ["TgtFolder3"]]
// ]


def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
builder.encoding = 'UTF-8'
def xml = builder.bind {
  mkp.xmlDeclaration()
  'udm.DeploymentPackage'(version:'$BUILD_NUMBER', application: "informaticaApp"){
    deployables {
      workflows.each { item ->
      'powercenter.PowercenterXml'(name:item.name, file:item.file){
        scanPlaceholders{ mkp.yield(true) }
        sourceRepository{ mkp.yield(item.sourceRepository) }
        'folderNameMap' {
          entry( key:"multifolder", "{{multifolderTST}}" )  // <- this is hard code and i want to remove this
        }
        'objectNames' {
          value { mkp.yield(item.objectName) }
        }
        'objectTypes' {
          value {  mkp.yield(item.objectType) }
        }
      }
    }
  }
    dependencyResolution{ mkp.yield('LATEST') }
    undeployDependencies{ mkp.yield(false) }
  }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

The resultant XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><udm.DeploymentPackage version="$BUILD_NUMBER" application="informaticaApp">
  <deployables>
    <powercenter.PowercenterXml name="A" file="fileA">
      <scanPlaceholders>true</scanPlaceholders>
      <sourceRepository>DEV2</sourceRepository>
      <folderNameMap>
        <entry key="multifolder">{{multifolderTST}}</entry>
      </folderNameMap>
      <objectNames>
        <value>wf_A</value>
      </objectNames>
      <objectTypes>
        <value>workflow</value>
      </objectTypes>
    </powercenter.PowercenterXml>
    <powercenter.PowercenterXml name="B" file="fileB">
      <scanPlaceholders>true</scanPlaceholders>
      <sourceRepository>DEV2</sourceRepository>
      <folderNameMap>
        <entry key="multifolder">{{multifolderTST}}</entry>
      </folderNameMap>
      <objectNames>
        <value>wf_B</value>
      </objectNames>
      <objectTypes>
        <value>workflow</value>
      </objectTypes>
    </powercenter.PowercenterXml>
  </deployables>
  <dependencyResolution>LATEST</dependencyResolution>
  <undeployDependencies>false</undeployDependencies>
</udm.DeploymentPackage>
```

This achieves the looping for the map declared as 'workflows' . There is another entry in the XML that needs to be iterated. The section in the script is

```
'folderNameMap' {
              entry( key:"multifolder", "{{multifolderTST}}" )  // <- this is hard code and i want to remove this
            }
```

I need to have this section iterated and create new line entries in the resulting XML, if multiple values were supplied to the script. Like:

```
  <folderNameMap>
    <entry key="multifolder">{{multifolderTST}}</entry>
    <entry key="multifolder2">{{multifolderTST2}}</entry>
    <entry key="multifolder3">{{multifolderTST3}}</entry>   
  </folderNameMap>
```

How can i define this 2nd map, so that the resultant XML looks like this: (the foldermap is a map. so i will have cases where only one srcFolder and a tgtFolder was given OR there will be times when there will be multiple srcFolder anb TgtFolders were given.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><udm.DeploymentPackage version="$BUILD_NUMBER" application="informaticaApp">
  <deployables>
    <powercenter.PowercenterXml name="A" file="fileA">
      <scanPlaceholders>true</scanPlaceholders>
      <sourceRepository>DEV2</sourceRepository>
      <folderNameMap>
        <entry key="multifolder">{{multifolderTST}}</entry>
      </folderNameMap>
      <objectNames>
        <value>wf_A</value>
      </objectNames>
      <objectTypes>
        <value>workflow</value>
      </objectTypes>
    </powercenter.PowercenterXml>
    <powercenter.PowercenterXml name="B" file="fileB">
      <scanPlaceholders>true</scanPlaceholders>
      <sourceRepository>DEV2</sourceRepository>
      <folderNameMap>
        <entry key="multifolder1">{{multifolderTST1}}</entry>
        <entry key="multifolder2">{{multifolderTST2}}</entry>
        <entry key="multifolder3">{{multifolderTST3}}</entry>
      </folderNameMap>
      <objectNames>
        <value>wf_B</value>
      </objectNames>
      <objectTypes>
        <value>workflow</value>
      </objectTypes>
    </powercenter.PowercenterXml>
  </deployables>
  <dependencyResolution>LATEST</dependencyResolution>
  <undeployDependencies>false</undeployDependencies>
</udm.DeploymentPackage>
```

Comment: Do you have a simpler example of what you mean? This is a huge question to digest in one go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm taking a stab in the dark here (as I'm not 100% sure I know what your question is), but assuming your input list can be changed to:

```
def workflows = [
    [ name: 'A',
      file: 'fileA',
      objectName: 'wf_A',
      objectType: 'workflow',
      sourceRepository: 'DEV2',
      folderNames: [ multifolder: '{{multifolderTST}}',
                     multifolder2: '{{multifolderTST2}}' ]],
    [ name: 'B',
      file: 'fileB',
      objectName: 'wf_B',
      objectType: 'workflow',
      sourceRepository: 'DEV2',
      folderNames: [ multifolder3: '{{multifolderTST3}}',
                     multifolder4: '{{multifolderTST4}}' ]]
]
```

Then, you can just do:

```
def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
builder.encoding = 'UTF-8'
def xml = builder.bind {
  mkp.xmlDeclaration()
  'udm.DeploymentPackage'(version:'$BUILD_NUMBER', application: "informaticaApp"){
    deployables {
      workflows.each { item ->
        'powercenter.PowercenterXml'(name:item.name, file:item.file) {
          scanPlaceholders(true)
          sourceRepository(item.sourceRepository)
          folderNameMap {
            item.folderNames.each { name, value ->
              entry(key:name, value)
            }
          }
          objectNames {
            value(item.objectName)
          }
          objectTypes {
            value(item.objectType)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    dependencyResolution('LATEST')
    undeployDependencies(false)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for. The iteration over the map inside a map.